# Table partitioning scheme with load job configuration

Tags: google-bigquery

According to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#converting_dated_tables_into_a_partitioned_table you can specify date partitioning options for BQ tables.

> Specify the partitioning configuration in the Tables::insert request

Since we do a lot of our ETL pipeline using load jobs, using `create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED'` I was wondering if there is a way to specify table partitioning scheme with the load job configuration.

Input appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now partitioned tables have to be created before a load job. We're working on the support of creating partitioned tables within a load/query job.

Answer (score 1):

Very keen on this too! The Spark Connector I am using does it via load jobs